# Changing variables dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on this thing, were I'd want to dynamically change values through a form with jQuery.

So far I have this (as an example):

```
var lat = [lat here];
var lng = [long here];
var radius = [radius here];

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url:  "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&distance=" + radius + " [more code here]
});
});
```

How can I make the lat, lng and radius dynamically through a form?
Hope somebody can help me.

If my story is a little bit unclear, I will try to explain it better!

Comment: That is the code (for the javascript file). The other file is my html file with a standard form (wich doesnt do anything yet)

Comment: @ManishKumar What for?

Comment: please explain it better ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.val()`.

```
<input type="text" id="latInput" />
...
var lat = $("#latInput").val();
```

I'll let you figure the other two out on your own =]

Some further information for others reading - I was at the jQuery UK conference this year when a very interesting chap gave a good talk about when *not* to use jQuery. One of the things you can do to keep the speed on your pages up is to not use `.val()` - it's faster (and almost as simple) to do

```
$("#element")[0].value
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Add a form to the page, and access the values via the [jQuery val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: createUrl()       
});


function createUrl() {
    var lat = $("#lat").val();
    var lng = $("#lng").val();
    var radius = $("#radius").val();
    return "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&distance=" + radius 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will let you grab the values from the input using the .val()

```
$("#latitude").val();
```

Use that val to assign to your variable:

```
lat = $("#latitude").val();
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure to grab the right input. So make sure to add an ID to the "input" item:

```
<input id="latitude" type="text"/>
```

Or whatever you're using.  Just make sure it has an "id" attribute and that you reference it in jQuery using "#" + id.